# How to implement secure frontend image upload?

Tags: images, ajax, uploads, security, front-end

I would like to implement an public image upload in my Wordpress Theme with ajax. 
What's the secure way to do this?

I have read many about security problems when allow users to upload files to the server.

And is it possible to prevent malicious images?

Comment: what exactly does this question has to do with wordpress? If you need security advice you better ask it in a security forum....

Comment: It may be better to phrase this as how to implement an AJAX file uploader in WordPress, while also specifying some constraints. It's a broad question ( almost too broad ) but still on topic. Perhaps it could be broken down into 2 parts, how to implement an AJAX file upload from the frontend, and how to secure that uploader to only work with images? That would make for 2 questions

Comment: @MarkKaplun Thank you for your fast reply. I'm not shure if its wordpress-specific. Wordpress have different handlers for ajax-upload and maybe some scurity features for file upload?

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you too for your fast reply. I'm interesting in both questions with focus on the second questions. But I am grateful if someone have a answer of one of both questions.

Comment: There are many security features in wordpress, but first you need to decide what kind of security you want to have

Comment: @Dennis you can edit your question to clarify, but keep in mind we have a 1 question per question policy. Simplifying your question and asking follow up questions rather than bundling it all in one question would dramatically increase the likelihood and the speed of getting an answer

Comment: @MarkKaplun I think the question is clear Q: "How do you implement a frontend uploader with AJAX, that only accepts valid images", aka if a PHP file or a javascript file is put in the uploader, it doesn't work, only images

Comment: @TomJNowell, Oh OK, there was too much detail there for my poor brain :)

Comment: But when people talk about image security, I by default add porm to that as people see degrading content as a "security" issue, and them there is an issue of how you limit sizes or traffic in general to prevent usage patterns which the OP might not like. PS in the past there used to be some security bugs triggered by image content. So for me checking mime type might be only one aspect of what is needed to be "fully secure"

Comment: If the OP wants to go one step further and add additional restrictions such as file size, dimensions, or age ratings/spam filtering/approval, I'm sure that can be covered in a new question, for the moment based on the question I think limiting it to testing if a file is or isn't an image would do the  job, likely using the same whitelist the media uploader uses